# youtube-dl is not downloading with specified format?

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, youtube, youtube-dl

So I'm trying to execute the following command. It downloads fine but although I specify `bestaudio` and `--audio-format wav` it does not download audio. And I cannot seem to be able to open the output files.

```
./youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p63EKPts9gw&list=PLfsJ7RXGJ4zZyaUA3OEhpZRq7S8PpPMFQ" -ci -f bestaudio -i -x --audio-format wav --min-sleep-interval 4 --max-sleep-interval 6 -o "news_%(playlist_index)03d.wav"
```

where I'm downloading a list of files and would like to only get the audio. However, this is what the output is.

```
news_001.wav: ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]
```

I cannot seem to open and listen to this file. I tried converting it to mp3 or wav with ffmpeg but it would tell me that it cannot find `waav`.

How can I extract only audio, possibly wav format, from that list?

Comment: -f is for video format according to the youtube-dl --help . you might also try other --audio-formats . alternative to download with audio and then strip audio out elsewise.

Answer (score -1):

Using [YoutubeDownloader](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader) with its "installYoutube-dl.sh" installer should get you to work. My goal writing this GUI wrapper was to eliminate any knowledge of the youtube-dl api.
Simply by dragging the url into its window should work - if not, open an issue ;-)

This app tries to get the best video and audio streams and joins them with ffmpeg.

Your wish to get  "wav" files will not work, since Youtube "optimizes" the uploads. So quality-wise this is probably the best you can get.

[image]